# sweet bay laurel with droopy/saggy leaves but no discoloration

Tags: diagnosis

I have two laurel shrubs, purchased from the same nursery two months ago, and re-potted on the day of purchase, in the same pot model, and same soil, growing next to each other. One proudly adorns the typical bright shiny green undulated-edge leaves (photo: right), but for the last month or so, the other one (photo: left), looks somewhat sadder, with saggier (pointing downwards), more matte and lighter green leaves.

There doesn’t look to be any irregular discoloration, and i don’t see any pests around the plant ot under the leaves.

Is there anything i should check to make sure the plant is okay?

[image: two laurels]

(Weather: I’m in Vancouver BC, and it is the end of june. Nice dry weather, ~25C normally, but there’s a heat wave this week (30-35C). The plants are on the outer edge of my balcony, facing north — partly shaded)

Comment: How long ago did you purchase these plants? And are you 100% sure the unhealthy one  is actually Laurus nobilis, bay laurel? You can tell by plucking a leaf and bending it to release the aromatics...

Comment: @Bamboo yep! smells and tastes like bay laurel. also identified as sweet bay laurel by the PictureThis app. bought 2 mo ago. updated text. thanks!